# Unable to query by date range in sqflite

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am unable to query by date range in sqflite. created_at dates are saved to IsoString and `start` and `end` are of format`yyyy-mm-dd`. the query is the following

```
await db!.rawQuery('''SELECT $mealTable.id as meal_id,
        $mealTable.meal_name, $ordersTable.* 
        FROM $ordersTable
        WHERE $orderCreatedAt >= '$start' AND $orderCreatedAt < '$end'
        LEFT JOIN $mealTable ON $mealTable.id = $ordersTable.order_meal'''
        );
```

This the error I get back

```
I/flutter (20062): ======error happened: DatabaseException(near "LEFT": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT meal_table.id as meal_id,
I/flutter (20062):         meal_table.meal_name, orders_table.*
I/flutter (20062):         FROM orders_table
I/flutter (20062):         WHERE created_at >= '2023-03-27' AND created_at < '2023-03-28'
I/flutter (20062):         LEFT JOIN meal_table ON meal_table.id = orders_table.order_meal) sql 'SELECT meal_table.id as meal_id,
I/flutter (20062):         meal_table.meal_name, orders_table.*
I/flutter (20062):         FROM orders_table
I/flutter (20062):         WHERE created_at >= '2023-03-27' AND created_at < '2023-03-28'
I/flutter (20062):         LEFT JOIN meal_table ON meal_table.id = orders_table.order_meal' args []====
```

can One spot the error before I go mad?

Comment: Your first problem is not using placeholders.  Fix that first, and your other problems might just disappear.

Comment: did `WHERE $orderCreatedAt BETWEEN ? AND ?', ['2022-01-01', '2022-12-31']` did same issue :(, if possible share whay the above doesn't work anyway @RandalSchwartz

Comment: What format are your dates?  sqlite doesn't have native date-time format, so it's all string representations, and you have to get those carefully.  Many people store epoch seconds for times so that ordering is at least proper.

Comment: my dates/time look  like this `2023-03-27T14:52:41.887678`. should I assume there are no DateTime functions too that come with sqlite. because I see alot of range date searches that look like the above on the internet but for some reason doesn't work for me. @RandalSchwartz

Comment: I see they  are some [dateTime functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). my knowledge with sql is limited help me use em.@RandalSchwartz

Comment: Try first JOIN, then WHERE

Comment: now I am getting `(1) ambiguous column name: created_at ` which is very wierd @HansKeﬆing

Comment: Then `created_at` exists in both tables. Prefix with the correct table name (or alias), like `orders_table.created_at`

Answer (score 1):

You should write rawquery like

```
somedb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeColumn = ?",["$element"])
```

You should write all variables in that square brackets.

Comment: i dont see how well this plays with isostring datetime

Comment: Also concatenate the string directly, no need for the placeholder

Comment: Don't concatenate, always use parameters to prevent sql injection

Comment: Ooh, got it learning new thing